# How do you perform transformation to each element and append the result in c++?

Tags: c++, algorithm, c++11, std, c++17

I have a set of integers {1,2}. I want to produce "Transform#1, Transform#2" where each element is tranformed and then result is accumulated with a delimiter.

What would be the easiest way to accomplish this? Do we have "folds", "maps" in c++?

We dont use boost.

Comment: Have you looked at [`std::transform`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/transform)

Comment: Can you provide a full example of what it is you actually want to do?

Comment: Are you asking if maps exist in c++, or something else. Because they do. See [here](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/map/map/)

Answer (score 15):

You can use `std::transform` and `std::accumulate`

```
int main()
{
  std::vector<int>         v1 {1,2,3};
  std::vector<std::string> v2;

  std::transform(begin(v1), end(v1), std::back_inserter(v2), [](auto const& i) {
    return std::string("Transform#") + std::to_string(i);
  });

  std::string s = std::accumulate(std::next(begin(v2)), end(v2), v2.at(0), [](auto const& a, auto const& b) {
    return a + ", " + b;
  });

  std::cout << s;
}
```

prints `Transform#1, Transform#2, Transform#3`

Comment: This is a good answer, but what happens if you change it to say `std::vector<int> v1;` at the beginning?

Comment: @Omnifarious thats right. I chose to change it to .at() so user can choose how best to handle it, if at all.

Answer (score 8):

You may want to use [Range Adaptors](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/ranges#Adaptors). Boost already has them and they are coming to the standard with C++20.

Take a look at the `boost::adaptors::transformed` example [here](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_68_0/libs/range/doc/html/range/reference/adaptors/reference/transformed.html).
Also, check out the [reference](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_68_0/libs/range/doc/html/range/reference/adaptors/reference.html) to get a better picture of what operations are supported by adaptors.

In the end, you can achieve much cleaner code and the performance difference is negligible (unlike in some other languages, where using this style of programming incurs heavy performance costs).

Answer (score 3):

If you can stand a trailing separator, the following function can transform any iterable range of data `{ X, ..., Z }` to the string `"<tag>X<sep>...<sep><tag>Z<sep>"`.

#### Code

```
template <class InputIt>
std::string f(InputIt begin, InputIt end, std::string_view separator = ", ", std::string_view tag = "Transform#")
{
    std::stringstream output;
    std::transform(begin, end,
        std::ostream_iterator<std::string>(output, separator.data()),
        [tag](auto const& element){ return std::string{tag} + std::to_string(element); }
    );
    return output.str();
}
```

It works by [transforming](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/transform) each element from the range into a [stream iterator](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/iterator/ostream_iterator).

#### Usage

```
int main()
{
    std::set<int> const data{1, 2, 3}; // works with vector, string, list, C-arrays, etc.
    std::cout << f(begin(data), end(data)) << '\n';
    // prints Transform#1, Transform#2, Transform#3, 
}
```

[Live demo](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/573db50e433a2782)

Answer (score 3):

You can perform a fold using simply [`std::accumulate`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/accumulate)

```
#include <set>
#include <string>
#include <iostream>
#include <numeric>

int main()
{
    auto transformation = [](int number) { return "Transform#" + std::to_string(number); };
    auto transform_and_fold = [&transformation](std::string init, int number) { return std::move(init) + ", " + transformation(number); };

    std::set<int> numbers{1, 2};
    std::cout << std::accumulate(std::next(numbers.begin()), numbers.end(), transformation(*numbers.begin()), transform_and_fold);
}
```

Outputs

`Transform#1, Transform#2`

Answer (score 3):

Assuming that I correctly understand the problem, the following straightforward implementation also looks very simple and easy.
This function works in C++11 and over:

[**DEMO with 5 test cases**](https://wandbox.org/permlink/WZdv2IkHjxs08dio)

```
std::string concatenate(
    const std::vector<int>& indecies, 
    const std::string& delimiter = ", ",
    const std::string& tag = "Transform#")
{
    if(indecies.empty()){
        return "";
    }

    std::string s(tag + std::to_string(indecies[0]));

    for(auto it = indecies.begin()+1; it != indecies.cend(); ++it){
        s += (delimiter + tag + std::to_string(*it));
    }

    return s;
}
```

(BTW, as for this function `concatenate`, if `indecies` is empty, the return value is also an empty string, not exceptions (AndreasDM's one) or UB (Everlight's one).
And if `indecies` has only a single element, for instance `indecies={1}`, then result is `"Transform#1”`, not `"Transform#1, ”`(YSC's one) or `", Transform#1”`(sakra's one).
These are different from other answers and this function will be more simpler if this handling is removed.)

---

Although the performance may not be a focal point, the above function can be slightly optimized by pre-reserving the minimum capacity to save the resulted string by `std::basic_string::reserve` as follows.
Here `+1` in `*.size()+1` means the minimum length of a number character.
I also removed `delimiter+tag` in the for-loop.
This still looks simple:

[**DEMO with 5 test cases**](https://wandbox.org/permlink/PUWCOpsU1z1ajE2T)

```
std::string concatenate_fast(
    const std::vector<int>& indecies, 
    std::string delimiter = ", ",
    const std::string& tag = "Transform#")
{
    if(indecies.empty()){
        return "";
    }

    std::string s(tag + std::to_string(indecies[0]));
    delimiter += tag;
    s.reserve((tag.size()+1) + (indecies.size()-1)*(delimiter.size()+1));

    for(auto it = indecies.begin()+1; it != indecies.cend(); ++it){
        s += (delimiter + std::to_string(*it));
    }

    return s;
}
```

I have also tested the performance of these functions and some proposed answers as follows.
These tests are done by *Quick C++ Benchmark* within gcc-8.2, C++17 and O3 optimization.
Since `std::transform_reduce` is still not available in Quick C++ Benchmark, I haven’t tested it.
The above `concatenate_fast` shows best performance at least in these cases and `concatenate` is second best.

Finally, just personally, taking the balance of the readability and the performance into account, I would like to propose the above `concatenate` as a solution:

**- Performance test with size 2 and 8.** ([**DEMO**](http://quick-bench.com/W-f6quZsLo9FGy1RUZwmDzjiPw0))

[image]

**- Performance test with size 16 and 32.** ([**DEMO**](http://quick-bench.com/aIKD-i5yoqWtleHPXM4d4ucXKmc))

[image]

Answer (score 2):

If you have the luxury of using C++17, there is a [standard library algorithm](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/transform_reduce) which does exactly what you need. Here is an example:

```
#include <iterator>
#include <iostream>
#include <numeric>
#include <string>

int main()
{
    auto input = {1, 2, 3};

    std::cout << std::transform_reduce(
        std::cbegin(input), std::cend(input),
        std::string("Result:"),
        [](const std::string & left, const std::string & right) { return left + " " + right; },
        [](int value) { return "Transform#" + std::to_string(value); }
    ) << "\n";
}
```

Comment: No that's not right, `reduce`'s order is non deterministic. You won't get the right order.

Comment: @Rakete1111 Thanks for the hint, you are right. `transform_reduce` can only be use for reduce operations which are both commutative and associative.

Answer (score 1):

Unless you have some other requirement to preserve the intermediate tranformed list, storing it is suboptimal. You can just call `std::accumulate` and do both operations on the fly:

```
#include <cstdio>
#include <iterator>
#include <numeric>

int main ( )
{
    int const input [] = { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6 };

    // computes sum of squares
    auto const add_square = [] ( int x, int y ) { return x + y * y; };
    int result = std::accumulate
        ( std::cbegin (input)
        , std::cend (input)
        , 0
        , add_square
        );

    std::printf ( "\n%i\n", result );

    return 0;
}
```